# Using SelectList I want to have one extra data text field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In the code below I would like for 'the data text field' to have both "FirstName" and "LastName" not only "FirstName" for the producers and actors.
I am using this for a dropdownlist.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    var movieDropdownsData = await _service.GetNewMovieDropdownsValues();            
    ViewBag.Cinemas = new SelectList(movieDropdownsData.Cinemas, "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.Producers = new SelectList(movieDropdownsData.Producers, "Id", "FirstName");
    ViewBag.Actors = new SelectList(movieDropdownsData.Actors, "Id", "FirstName");
    return View();
}
```

From what I read I have to add and extra 'data text field' but I don't know how.

Comment: FWIW you can use a view model with those `SelectList` in that model and pass that to the view as a proper model rather than `ViewBag` yourself crazy to make it more robust/ testable etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you modify your classes to have something like this - with proper names/format perhaps. Then just use that

```
public string FullName { get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;}  }
```

Alternative expression bodied syntactic sugar with interpolated string

```
public string FullName => $"{this.FirstName} {this.LastName}";
```

OR use the prior way to put the string together there `this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName`, or `String.Concat()` or `String.Format()` as required for your needs

- Ref: Blog https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/new-features-in-c-7-0/
- Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties
- Ref string interpolation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was too dumb to do this in the first place.

Comment: Yea, making "good" classes vs "better" is sometimes subjective - one reason there are "View" classes and "Data" classes since a View would typically have this but not a Data class - which is more about mapping and data access. I will add the newer version to this answer in case someone has desire to use that form/format of syntactic sugar also.